# ReSharper: Refactor to eliminate an in-between interface

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have a situation where I now have an `interface` with nothing in it:

```
public interface IStuffEx : IStuff
{
}
```

It made sense in the past but, we've moved everything in it to `IStuff`, because of mix/match issues.

I have 187 uses of `IStuffEx` that I need to change to `IStuff`.

Does ReSharper have a refactor to do this? I assumed it does but I can't find it.

Comment: I was worried a search/replace might touch other things. Refactoring is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! It's ["use base type where possible."](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Use_Base_Type_Where_Possible.html) Worked like a charm and replaced every use.

You still have the interface after the refactoring runs, but it's not in use anywhere. So then you can delete it.

Comment: I would have just deleted `IStuffEx` renamed `IStuff` to `IStuffEx` and then do a rename refactor back to `IStuff`.  Nice to know there's a less hacky way.